# Find all hyperplanes separating unique sets of `k` points

Tags: cg.comp-geom

I have a series of `n` points in `d`-dimensional continuous space.  I want to find a series of hyperplanes such that `k` points are below the hyperplane and that the set of `k` points below each hyperplane is a unique set.  It does not matter what the hyperplane is (e.g. if it connects `d` points or if it is another hyperplane not intersecting any points).  I can discretise the space if it helps.  "below" is defined as the negative direction for the first dimension.

The way I have approached is to try all hyperplanes defined by all sets of `d` points, project each point on to this hyperplane, and test if the projection is above the point.  This results in `n^(d+1)` complexity.

Is there a better way?  What is it?

Comment: Why do you want to compute this ?

Comment: It's a component of an algorithm for work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you are interested in the $k$-set problem:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-set_(geometry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-set_%28geometry%29)

In general their number can be $O(n^{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}k^{\lceil d/2\rceil})$ and though I could not find references now, I think you can also compute them in about this much time.

Comment: My fear was that this question was a homework question: that's why I asked for the motivation .

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was looking for.  Didn't know there was a similar problem with a name.  I thought about something like Edelsbrunner and Welzl (1986) viewed in terms of k-sets of point sets but couldn't formalise it.  Time to learn about bitangents!